# How do I filter a javascript object when making a search pipe with angular 2?

Tags: javascript, filter, typescript, angular

I'm trying to create a search pipe for Angular 2.
It should take a nested object and filter out the objects matching a search term.
I have a basic version working but I have run into two problems.

Problem one is, that I now have to hard code key names or use what seems to me like a dirty hack with `JSON.stringify`.

What is a more elegant way to filter the object, matching the term with any value exept a list of hardcoded ones like `_id` and `url`?

Problem two is, that if the string `term` contains a space, I would like to split it and filter the `obj` with both terms.
I can split it using `terms = term.split(' ');`.

But how do I achive filtering with multiple terms?

My current code:

```
import {Pipe} from 'angular2/core';

@Pipe({
    name: "search"
})
export class SearchPipe{
    transform(obj: any, [term]) {
        if (obj != null && term) {
            return obj.filter( el => {

                //var test = JSON.stringify(el); 
                //return test.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase()); //trows a compile error but seems to work.

                return el.name.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase()) || el.place.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase()) || el.title.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase()) ;

            });

        } else {
            return obj;
        }
    }
}
```

Expected input format:

```
[
{
  "_id": "56ffbe512ba199777d51c6ae",
  "picture": "http://placehold.it/36x36",
  "name": "Melissa Reeves",
  "company": "Orbixtar",
  "place": "Greenwich, Belarus",
  "title": "voluptate est ipsum",
  "location": {
    "lat": -78.926961,
    "lng": 90.157653
  },
  "url": "http://lol.lol"
},
{
  "_id": "56ffbe5119cf66e94b3800b4",
  "picture": "http://placehold.it/36x36",
  "name": "Chelsea Lindsay",
  "company": "Squish",
  "place": "Vowinckel, Belarus",
  "title": "anim ea exercitation",
  "location": {
    "lat": 66.547582,
    "lng": 162.720388
  },
  "url": "http://lol.lol"
}
]
```

If the term is `"term1"` I would like it to return objects that contains "term1".

If on the otherhand term is `"term1 term2 term3"` I would like for it to return all objects that contain all terms but not necessarily in that specific order.

As an exaple.

The term `"Melissa"` should return the first object.

The term `"Melissa Belarus"` should also return only the first object.
Even though the second object matches one of the keys.

Comment: Prefer `(el) => {` over `function (el) {` to retain the scope of `this` with the class instead of the function.

Comment: Can you please add an example what the result should look like exactly for a concrete `term`?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. its good to know.
I have added an example for term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this** (untested)

```
@Pipe({
  name: "search"
})
export class SearchPipe{
  transform(obj: any, [term]) {
    if (obj != null && term) {
      return obj.filter( el => {

        var test = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(el));
        delete test['url'];
        delete test['_id'];

        var testString = JSON.stringify(test);

        Object.keys(test).forEach(k => {
          testString = testString.replace(k, '');
        });

        let terms = term.replace(/[\s]+/gm, " ").replace(/^[\s]|[\s]$/gm, "").split(' ');
        let containCount = 0;

        terms.forEach(t => {
          if(testString.toLowerCase().indexOf(t.toLowerCase()) > -1)
          {
            ++containCount;
          }
        });

        return (containCount == terms.length);
      });

    } else {
      return obj;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This works for one term with some edits. indexOf does not always return true so have to test for  `!== -1`, second problem is that, when splitting the string you get an empty value where the space was. as in `["term1",,"term2"]` i solved this with  `let newArray = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < terms.length; i++) {
                        if (terms[i]) {
                            newArray.push(terms[i]);
                        }
                    }`

Comment: The tird problem with this solution is that is does not match both terms, it  returns objects matching any of the terms. wich is not my desired result.
Thank you for taking your time :)

Comment: My bad... to clearly understand your requirement it would take some more info about desired input and output....  That's nothing.

Comment: I added an exaple in my question. I hope that makes it clear. :)

Comment: never mind my problem with the array containing empty elements. a siple `.trim()` solved that

Comment: I updated my answer solving the three issues that you pointed, see if it works